# Svelte: show <input> empty if bound value equal to specific value and show value otherwise

Tags: svelte

With:

```
<input bind:value={qtyMax} />
```

Target behaviour:
Input shows nothing if qtyMax === -1, and qtyMax value otherwise.

I have an idea to do it in a dirty way with js... like changing input CSS class regarding qtyMax value, if qtyMax === -1 : input text white, and on:focus changes qtyMax to '' (to avoid double delete for '-1').

Is there a nicer way with Svelte ?

Comment: I like your dirty trick, it’s actually a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a nice way of dealing with this; besides inputs showing their value as is, the value also is string-based.

I would recommend transforming the value, e.g. when the page loads, `-1` would be transformed to the empty string, and when the value has to be extracted again, an inverse transformation happens. What these points are depends on what the input is for/how it is used.

Otherwise you end up with circular dependencies that are hard to work with and can cause weird edge cases with unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yes that's what I used to do, mixing string and number... but you know once you tried TypeScript hard to accept such looseness on types ;-)